# Static resources with undertow, from a fatjar

Tags: java, servlets, undertow

```
private static HttpHandler createHandler(HttpHandler servletHandler) {
    return Handlers.path()
                   .addExactPath("/", resource(new PathResourceManager(Paths.get("src/main/resources/Index.html"), 100))
                           .setDirectoryListingEnabled(false)) // resolves index.html
                   .addPrefixPath(Context.getPath(), servletHandler)
                   .addPrefixPath("/static", resource(new PathResourceManager(Paths.get("src/main/resources/"))));

}
```

the above works from my IDE, but fails from the fatjar ?

Answer (score 2):

When you're running it in the IDE, it's not in a jar and you can access resources normally on the filesystem with paths. When you're running inside a jar, you need to access the resources inside the jar file.

Use `ClassPathResourceManager` for that. It works outside the jar too, as long as the resource is on the classpath.

Comment: Where is the best place for documentation

Comment: http://undertow.io/javadoc/1.3.x/io/undertow/server/handlers/resource/ClassPathResourceManager.html there's the javadoc at least.